# How to use the Monte Carlo method with curve fitting

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, monte-carlo

I have an assignment in which I need to choose statistical data from the Australian Bureau of Statistics and fit a curve to it.

I've chosen the [slaughtering of bulls in NSW](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/7218.0.55.001Aug%202015?OpenDocument) (first Excel file, C:143-C:612).

Using MATLAB's `fminsearch` I came up with the damped oscillation curve

$$ y=A_5+A_1e^{-A(2)x} \sin(A(3)x-A(4)) $$
with parameter values

$$A(1)=50.1759,A(2)=0.0080,A(3)=0.0341,A(4)=-1.0756,A(5)=78.8225 $$

which produced the following picture:

[image]

Next, I'm asked to use the Monte-Carlo Method to get further predictions, which I should then average. I can't see how to insert the randomness here, as each data point is only measured once, meaning that the suggested formula

$$newvalue=oldvaluemean+randn()*SEM $$

reduces to

$$newvalues=oldvaluemean=oldvalue $$

Am I doing anything wrong? How can one use the Monte Carlo method here?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. In general, there are many Monte Carlo methods. 'THE Monte Carlo method' may make sense in some context you are not sharing with us, and which you should explain.

Comment: Are you trying to assess prediction accuracy using MC methods?

Comment: @BruceET Apparently, I need to recreate the data values using the above formula. The problem is that I don't know what the means and standard errors are. I tried calling the ABS and they said there are no errors in the measurements, which makes this question impossible to do anyway.

Comment: @Bey See my previous comment.

Comment: What do you mean "recreate the data using the formula"...it appears you will need to fit a model to the residuals of your formula.

Comment: I think you are expected to (1) subtract the curve from the data; (2) pick a distribution that fits these residuals (normal, or maybe uniform; with standard deviation to be computed from data); (3) add random samples from this distribution to your curve. The result should be a simulated cloud similar to the original data.